# Create VM on Azure with an existing VHD

Tags: powershell, virtual-machines, azure, vhd

I'm trying to create a virtual machine on MS Azure plaftorm, from my existing VHD file. When i'm trying to, I get the following error. Is there any parameter to specify the NIC? Did some research on the web with no suitable results.

```
PS C:\Users\Rav> azure vm create --os-disk-vhd https://group11492.blob.core.windows.net/vhds/Integration201641775831.vhd

info:    Executing command vm create
    Resource group name: Default-Storage-WestUS
    Virtual machine name: integration201641775831v
    Location name: West US
    Operating system Type: Linux
    + Looking up the VM "integration201641775831v"
    info:    Using the VM Size "Standard_DS1"
    error:   Either NIC Id or NIC name is required
    info:    Error information has been recorded to C:\Users\Rav\.azure\azure.err
    error:   vm create command failed
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes,

...

```
-I, --nic-ids <nic-ids>             the list of NIC identifiers separated by comma. 
                                    In case of specifying multiple nics first one
                                    will be set as primary.
-N, --nic-names <nic-names>         the list of NIC names separated by comma. 
                                    In case of specifying multiple nics first 
                                    one will be set as primary.These NICs must 
                                    exists in the same resource group as the VM. 
                                    Please use nic-ids if that not the case. 
                                    This parameter will be ignored if --nic-ids 
                                    is specified
```

...

If you do not see those parameters, you may want to update your azure cli.